# javascript function toString'd with dynamic values embedded?

Tags: javascript, function, serialization

I'm calling `toString()` on a function so that I can send it across the wire to a system that will apply it against an object. A simplified example is below. Here I am pushing the function as a string to a remote service, which is checking if the remote object `this`, which has the property `timestamp`, is older than `cutoff` which is currently always one house ago...

```
var functionToSend = function() { 

    let cutoff = new Date();
    cutoff.setHours(autoApproveCutoff.getHours() - 1);

    const isMatch = this.timestamp <= cutoff

    return isMatch
};

foo.sendFunction(functionToSend.toString())
```

I'd like to be able to sent the `cutoff` hour (either at build **or** runtime), whilst maintaining `functionToSend` as an actual function so I can unit test and enjoy autocomplete, colourisation etc. Plus, if i end up with 100 checks for 100 different cutoff values I don't want to have to maintain them all separately.

```
    cutoff.setHours(autoApproveCutoff.getHours() - DYNAMIC-VALUE);
```

Bear in mind that once the function is stringified you can't reference anything external to the function (except thos `this` which is the remote object).

Might be impossible. Might be more effort than it's worth. But would be interested if anyone has any ideas, short of code-gen.

Comment: Can't you have a factory function that accepts a cutoff time and returns the function to stringify? Idk if you can stringify a function that has a closure over variables.

Comment: Exactly :) my question is pretty much, how would I do that? You are right, the problem is when you have closure over variables it will stringify the var name that is being referenced. I would need it to swap out that var name for the value, like baking in a const value but dynamically. Like I said, possibly impossible, but thought I'd ask :)

Comment: You could try embedding the function and the cutoff in an object, then have the function reference the cutoff somehow. Then serialize the entire object. You'd have to get creative to get that working though. Good luck.

Comment: I guess there is a crude approach that involves doing a string replace `getHours() - 1)` with `getHours() - 5)` or some such, but it feels pretty grubby :/